# Determining whether or not an object is a PHPUnit mock

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I would like to assert that a value/object passed into a PHPUnit test method is a mock that was initialized by getMockBuilder. E.g.:

```
class Example_Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    ...

    public function testMethod(Some_Class $object_mock)
    {

        // since methods like "expects" will be used below,
        // this needs to be a mock
        assert('$this->isMock($object_mock)');

        ...

        $object_mock->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
                    ->method('reallyCoolThingThatMustHappen')
                    ->with(
                        $this->equalTo('absolutely_necessary_argument')
                    );

        ...

    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a method that can be used to assert that `$object_mock` is a PHPUnit mock? (I know isMock doesn't exist, but I put it there as an example of what I'm trying to do).

Comment: Well your mock can be set to return a true when an `isMock()` method is called: `$object_mock->method('isMock')
             ->willReturn(true);`

Comment: @MarkBaker Great idea. But I'd also need for it to return false if it's not a mock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$o instanceof PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject` evaluates to `true` when `$o` is a test double that was created using the `getMock()` (deprecated), `getMockWithoutInvokingTheOriginalConstructor()` (deprecated), `createMock()` (best practice), `createConfiguredMock()`, `createPartialMock()`, `getMockBuilder()`, etc. methods.